# Using REGEXP_Substr in db for more than one condition

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Hi i'm using SQL Query in ORACLE db.
How can i use the function REGEXP_SUBSTR (oracle SQL) to create a new column with name "VOIE" that contains just the type of "VOIE" and if there's not it said NULL.
Here's an exemple of my data frame:

```
SP_PK  LIB                                         NAME
234    Voie orale, 2cpr, dès demain                jojo
298    2cpr, dès la semaine pro                    tata
302    Voie buccale, 1 gélule par jour             lobi
209    NULL                                        sola
```

What i want to have:

```
SP_PK  LIB                                         NAME    VOIE
234    Voie orale, 2cpr, dès demain                jojo    Voie orale
298    2cpr, dès la semaine pro                    tata    NULL
302    Voie buccale, 1 gélule par jour             lobi    Voie buccale
209    NULL                                        sola    NULL
```

Comment: If present at all, will `Voie` always be at the very beginning of `LIB`? Also, how much do you need to extract - exactly two words? Exactly everything up to the first comma (or end of string if there is no comma)? What else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (lib) as
  2    (select 'Voie orale, 2cpr, dès demain'    from dual union all
  3     select '2cpr, dès la semaine pro'        from dual union all
  4     select 'Voie buccale, 1 gélule par jour' from dual union all
  5     select null                              from dual union all
  6     select 'what is voie anyway?'            from dual
  7    )
  8  select lib,
  9         regexp_substr(lib, 'voie \w+', 1, 1, 'i') voie
 10  from test;

LIB                               VOIE
--------------------------------- ------------------------------
Voie orale, 2cpr, dcs demain      Voie orale
2cpr, dcs la semaine pro
Voie buccale, 1 gélule par jour   Voie buccale

what is voie anyway?              voie anyway

SQL>
```

Comment: Input `Haute-Savoie Mont Blanc`, output `voie Mont`. Very unlikely to be the desired handling.

Comment: True, @mathguy. Though, how is it likely that *input* would be something like that? It's about *medicine*, I don't speak French so - as far as sample data is concerned, that kind of "works". If there really are such cases (that "voie" is a substring in another word), then yes, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

I should think that it is not necessary to use REGEXP... REGEX is very costly !

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LIB, instr(' ' || LIB, ' voie '), instr('LIB, ',') - instr(' ' || LIB, ' voie ')
```

Comment: Fera l'affaire - peut-etre. For example what if there is a comma **preceding** the delivery method? See also my comment to the other answer.

Comment: The other solution trouble won't be seen in mine because I add a blank before the LIB to avoid partial word voie like SAVOIE. Of course the trouble with multiple comma can be avoid with a INSTR that accept to begin after the "voie" with the LocateN function